# Data Structure for happened before relationship in C++

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, distributed-system

What is the best structure for maintaining a global happened before relationship in C++. I was thinking of array of linked lists(Array is each process and items in the linked lists are events). But it will be difficult to find out the cycles between different process. Can anybody suggest good data structure to maintain the global relationship? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there is a universal order of happened before, why would there be cycles?

Answer (score 0):

[Boost's](http://boost.org/) [Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) has data structures and algorithms useful to detect cycles in directed graphs.